# Python3 Bytestreams and UDP

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, udp

I'm trying to send a packet that needs to arrive at its destination as hex in the form:
`01 02 a1 a2 b1 b2`

In Python2, the UDP method to send that would be:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.send(message, (UDP_IP, UDP_Port))
```

Message could be passed a hex string like:
`\x01\x02\xa1\xa2\xb1\xb2` and that would arrive in the correct format.

In Python3, I cannot pass message the same value without getting the error `str does not support the buffer interface`. The problem then being is that if I pass message a bytestream `b'\x01\x02\xa1\xa2\xb1\xb2'` It will not arrive in the correct format.

Has anyone got any suggestions (other than port to 2.7)?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

#Import block
import gzip, zlib
import time
import binascii
import struct
import socket

#Start of code
def compress():
    """The function to compress the packet"""
    with open('results/file', 'r') as f:
        '''Open the file with all the stuff in'''
        for lines in f.readlines():
            '''Each line represents one packet that will be sent'''
            lines = (lines.strip("\n")) #Make sure their are no stray new lines
            lines = lines.encode('UTF-8') #Encode for compression
            compressed = gzip.compress(lines, 6)
            pureHex = (binascii.hexlify(compressed))
    return pureHex

def generator(pureHex):
    """The function to add the additional information to the packet"""  
    packet = [pureHex[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(pureHex), 2)]
    packet = b'\\x' + b'\\x'.join(packet) #Add the \\x that's needed
    packet = packet.decode('UTF-8') #Requires decoding to remove the silly second \ that you have to add
    return packet


def post(packet):
    """The function to post/send the message via UDP"""
    sock.sendto(packet, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,
            socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    UDP_IP = "101.101.101.101" #Target IP Address
    UDP_PORT = 5010 #Target Port Number
    pureHex = compress()
    packet = generator(pureHex)
    post(packet)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it will not arrive in the correct format"?

Comment: Correct being the format shown in the first sentence. As its a bytestream it'll somehow magically arrive at the other end (in Wireshark) as a completely different value. Looking at the first 5 bytes (py3), sent: `\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01` received `5c7830315c`

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Wireshark reports "0102a1a2b1b2" as the sent data. Can you post a functional script illustrating the problem?

Comment: Added. The double \\ problem is that sending the bytestream with \\ won't work, but neither will it work as UTF-8. :(

Comment: I'm a little confused by your spec. Are you *100% sure* that the packets actually need to arrive as `0102a1...` instead of `\x01\x02\xa1...`? You seem to be confusing `\x00` with `\x` + `00`.

Comment: Don't worry - I'm confused too! The packets certainly need to arrive as 0102a1. The only way I found of doing that was by sending hex in python2.7 `send('\x01\x02\xa1')`. The packet on arrival would then read as `0102a1`. Py3's handling of buffers really has made this incredibly difficult (hence the questions)! :)

Comment: `\x01` isn't hex, though. `'\x01\x02' == chr(1) + chr(2)` is a two-byte string.

Comment: Trust me when I say the values are hexadecimal - it may not be expressed clearly, but they are.

Comment: Well, what you're sending is what the other side is receiving. Should the other side be receiving the bytes with escape sequences `\1` and `\2`, or the bytes `0`, `1`, `0`, and `2`?

Comment: 0, 1, 0, 2 it should arrive as.

Comment: A solution was found in Python2.7. Question flagged for closure.

Answer (score 0):

You should send `compressed` directly and drop all other code that converts bytes to a hex string only to try to convert it back using an pseudo-emulation of Python representation for bytestrings.

Learn how bytes differ from their hex representation in Python source code:

```
>>> import binascii
>>> b = binascii.unhexlify('0102') # hex string to bytes
>>> b
b'\x01\x02' # representation: repr(b)
>>> len(_)
2
>>> b'\\x01\\x02' #XXX it is not what you want
b'\\x01\\x02'
>>> len(_)
8
>>> repr(b)
"b'\\x01\\x02'" # repr of a repr
>>> repr(repr(b))
'"b\'\\\\x01\\\\x02\'"' # repr of a repr of a repr
```

Answer (score -1):

You need encode the packet. Change the line:

```
post(packet)
```

to:

```
post(bytes(packet,"utf-8"))
```

This worked for me.